# How to Get the Specified Tags for SequenceB in MT204

Tags: java

When obtaining tag using following approach

```
MT204.SequenceB sequenceB = mt204.getSequenceBList().get(i);
transactionReferenceNumberSeqB[i] = (Field20) sequenceB.getFieldByName("20");
```

the value filled from `SequenceA` which also contain an item with `Field20`. Not from the `SequenceBList`.

What went wrong ?

When I check i debug mode 'sequenceB` contains all the tags, how that happens.

Comment: Could you please clarify the question further?  Not sure what the expected output is.

Comment: I expect the value from sequenceB let say "123" which is in sequenceB as "20:123" but I am getting value in sequenceA let say "134" which is in sequence a as "20:134"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by using the full list and correctly putting the field Id.

```
SwiftBlock4 block4 = mt20x.getSwiftMessage().getBlock4();
if(index < block4.countAll()) // this helps to avoid null pointer exception
{
   Field fieldVal = block4.getField(index) // where index should be correct values to match the order
 }
```